# How to hide Attribute for a particular category

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

i have 3 category on my website Mens, Womens, Childrens. I added another attribute as Sub Category which is only for Childrens to identify weather its a Boy or a Girl products. But the problem is that Sub Category is showing in Mens and Womens Category as N/A. So how can i hide that Sub Category in just Mens & Womens. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create separate attribute set for this ? otherwise you should add some condition in your template that not show all those attributes where there is no value specified.

Comment: You want do : if the attribute value is N/A, you don't display it ?

Comment: yes as sub category is only for childrens and showing NA in mens and womens section seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{themename}/template/catalog/product/view/attributes/phtml

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
   <table class="table table-striped push-top">
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <?php if( $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) != "N/A") :?> //Added this condition
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Update:**

Replace

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

with :

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php if( $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) != "N/A") :?> //Added this condition
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Update2:**

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php if(!empty($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']))) :?> //Added this condition
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Should i replace it with anything or simply add this line ?

Comment: What should you replace it with anything ? you go to this file : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{themename}/template/catalog/product/view/attributes/phtml` then you add this contion `            <?php if( $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) != "N/A") :?>` like my exemple

Comment: did not work .... i copy pasted your code by replacing my existing one.

Comment: Share me please your original code

Comment: how can i copy paste the code as its showing to long

Comment: Just the code of `app/design/frontend/{package}/{themename}/template/catalog/product/view/attributes/phtml` you Edit the topic and you past it

Comment: done added the Screenshot for it..

Comment: @Patrik Look my update please

Comment: I tried it didn't work..

Comment: I don't know why, I tested it and it works for me, What is the the values of your attribute `Sub category` that you created in admin ? can you post some screenshot of that

Comment: i have attached the Screenshot.

Comment: Now the other tab please, when you set the option value

Comment: done added the SS.

Comment: Yes of sourse, it should not work like this, please look my update2

Comment: tried didnt work as well.

Comment: haha, We will get there, please add this : `<?php Zend_Debug::dump($this->__($_data['code'])); ?>
        <?php Zend_Debug::dump($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])); ?>` just after `<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>` and tel me the result

Comment: nope didn't work...

Comment: How it doesn't work ? it should display something, here is the complete piece code `<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <?php Zend_Debug::dump($this->__($_data['code'])); ?>
        <?php Zend_Debug::dump($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])); ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>`

Answer (score -1):

Please Copy this file in your theme direcrtory if it not available in your active theme:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

**And replace this code**

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**with following code**

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <?php if($_data['value'] != "N/A"): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will hide attributes with value "N/A".

Comment: i tried it didn't work.

Comment: I think your product information block shows from custom template file, Please enable template path hint and check this product info. Shows from which file and apply condition in that file.

Comment: i tried finding it using pathfinder, but the area is not highlighted and no location showed. any other way to know this ?

Comment: can you just share screenshot with enabled path hints for that block?

Comment: i added the screenshot in my main post above. Thanks

Comment: I checked screenshot, there not shows any file for information block,
you need to find manually that template file.